# Determine values $a$,$b$, and $c$ such that the graph of $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ has a relative maximum at $(3, 12)$ and crosses the $y$-axis at $(0,1)$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I understand to find $c$ we incorporate the point at the $y$-axis $(0,1)$ into the question which gives us $c=1$ but I can't seem to get the correct numbers for $a$ and $b$.

If you could help that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Hint...you have $$-\frac{b}{2a}=3$$ and $$9a+3b+c=12$$

And you already know $c$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: use "Coordinates of the vertex"

> $$\left( -\frac { b }{ 2a } ,\frac { 4ac-{ b }^{ 2 } }{ 4a }  \right) $$

so   we have $$\begin{cases} -\frac { b }{ 2a } =3 \\ \frac { 4a-{ b }^{ 2 } }{ 4a } =12 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} b=-6a \\ { b }^{ 2 }=-44a \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} b=-6a \\ 36{ a }^{ 2 }=-44a \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} b=\frac { 22 }{ 3 }  \\ a=-\frac { 11 }{ 9 }  \end{cases}$$

Comment: Im just a bit confused on how you got that coordinate at the top.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this using calculus because the question does have a calculus tag on it (as of the time I write this).

So far you have $y = ax^2 + bx + 1$.

What does it mean for $y$ to have a relative maximum at $(3,12)$?  It means that when $x = 3$, the function has a relative maximum, and the value of the relative maximum is $y = 12$.

Now, what does it mean in terms of the derivative?  Recall that at any relative maximum or minimum, the derivative is zero (or undefined, which is a non-issue here since $y$ is a polynomial).  If $y = ax^2 + bx + 1$, then $y' = 2ax + b$.  So we know that when $x = 3$, we have $y' = 0$.  Therefore we have $0 = 2a(3) + b$, which simplifies to $$ 6a + b = 0.$$

Also, in order for $y$ to have a relative maximum at $(3,12),$ it's a requirement that $(3,12)$ is actually a point on the graph.  In other words, when $x = 3$ we know that $y = 12$.  This gives us another equation:
$$ 9a + 3b + 1 = 12$$

So we have two linear equations with two unknowns $a$ and $b$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. Would we then sub b into the original equation or derivative?

Comment: No subbing of $b$ anywhere.  Your next step would be to solve the system of equations to get the values of $a$ and $b$.  Then you'll have $a$, $b$ and $c$, which means you'll have found the function $y$.

Answer (score 0):

So if you consider that you've already found $c$ then you're left with two unknown values. Algebra tells us that we will need two equations to solve for these. The first is the equation that you're given. Since we know that $(3,12)$ is a point on the graph, we can simply plug in $(3,12)$ for $(x,y)$ in the equation to achieve the following:
$$
    12 = 9a + 3b + 1
$$
That's the first equation. See here that we only have two unknown values in this equation now.

The second equation will come from taking the derivative of your original function:
\begin{align*}
    y &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    \frac{dy}{dx} &= 2ax + b
\end{align*}
We know that since the relative max occurs at $(3,12)$ we know that $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ and $x = 3$ so plugging in we have:
$$
    0 = 6a + b
$$
So that results in our two equations being:
\begin{align*}
    11 &= 9a + 3b \\
    0 &= 6a + b
\end{align*}

Now you have two equations and two unknowns. Solve :)

Answer (score 0):

The relative maximum of a quadratic function occurs at the vertex of its graph.  The vertex form of the function is 
$$y = a(x - h)^2 + k$$
where $(h, k)$ is the vertex.  We know that $(h, k) = (3, 12)$, so we have 
$$y = a(x - 3)^2 + 12$$
We also know that the graph has $y$-intercept $1$.  Hence, 
\begin{align*}
1 & = a(0 - 3)^2 + 12\\
1 & = 9a + 12\\
-11 & = 9a\\
-\frac{11}{9} & = a
\end{align*}
Hence, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
y & = -\frac{11}{9}(x - 3)^2 + 12\\
  & = -\frac{11}{9}(x^2 - 6x + 9) + 12\\
  & = -\frac{11}{9}x^2 + \frac{22}{3}x - 11 + 12\\
  & = -\frac{11}{9}x^2 + \frac{22}{3}x + 1
\end{align*}
so $a = -\dfrac{11}{9}$, $b = \dfrac{22}{3}$, and $c = 1$.